# Generalized List as a parameter for a method

Tags: java, arraylist

Say I have a simple class like this:

```
public class BasicObject {
    private String name;

    public BasicObject (String str) {
        name = str;
    }

    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }
}
```

then I have some simple method in the main class like this:

```
private static int findInList (____ list, String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(str)) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

It would work if I put `List<BasicObject>` on the blank for the parameter `list`, but what if I have other objects? Can I generalize the list so this would work with other objects besides `BasicObject`? If so, how can I get the type of the objects in the list?

Edit: What if I have another class from an imported package that I can still put in a list but I don't want to change what it implements? Is there a way to have a generalized `findInList` that includes those too? Or do I have to just make another method for that? I'm fine with just making another method, but I'm curious if this way is possible.

Comment: What kind of other objects? Do you intend to invoke `getName()`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, other objects also with a `getName()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an interface structure such as this

Doing so provides a common call structure, so it is predictable what can be called from the implementations

```
public interface IShape {
    String getName();
}

public class Square implements IShape {
    private String name = "Square";
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public class Circle implements IShape {
    private String name = "Circle";
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    List<IShape> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new Square());
    list.add(new Circle());
    list.add(new Circle());
    list.add(new Square());
    list.add(new IShape() {
        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return "Triangle";
        }
    });

    for(IShape test : list){
        System.out.println(test.getName());
    }
}
```

this produces an output like this

> Square
>
> Circle
>
> Circle
>
> Square
>
> Triangle

*as answer to edit*

Yes, but requires reflection, if help is needed on this, please open a new question after proberly trying to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: Those class/interface names are really confusing.

Comment: Right, well suppose i can change that

Comment: I was thinking to use public interface Namable

Comment: @NickZiebert  Sure, i suppose, then just NameableImpl1, 2 etc ? or any ideas ?

Comment: @NickZiebert Allright, keeping it as is then :), figured it was pretty basic example for the sake of understanding :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)? It is what you're looking for, your method signature should look like below:

```
public <T> List<T> findInList (Class<T> list, String str) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work if all objects have common parent (BasicObject or any other class which have getName() method).

```
private static int findInList (List<? extends BasicObject> list, String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i).getName().equalsIgnoreCase(str)) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code relies on the list having an element type with a `getName` method that is visible to the compiler. Another way is to use lambdas. For example,

```
public interface Named {
  String getName();
}

public class UseNamed<T extends Named> {

public int findIndex(List<T> nameds, String search) {
  for (int len = nameds.size(), ix = 0; ix < len; ++ix) {
    final Named named = names.get(ix);
    if (search.equalsIgnoreCase(named.getName())) {
      return ix;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

One approach with lambdas is to pass a comparer to `findIndex`:

```
public <T, K> int findIndex(List<T> stuff, K search,
    BiFunction<T, K, Boolean> compares) {...}
```

and call it with

```
List<Named> stuff = ...;
String search = ...;
int index = findIndex(stuff, search,
    (named, s) -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(named.getName()));
```